# How to mock the instance function of another class using Jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I have two classes for eg:

```
//MyClass.ts
import {B} from '../MyAnotherClass'
class A {
  f1(){ }
  f2(){ 
    const instance = new B();
    instance.someBFunctionFoo(arg);
  }
}

// MyAnotherClass.ts
class B {
  someBFunctionFoo(arg){ }
  someBFunctionBar(){ }
}
```

I want to write test cases for class A but i don't want class A to actually invoke class B instance functions rather call a mocked version of those functions. How can this be achieved using Jest. I am using typescript and running test cases against the typescript rather the compiled js files.

Comment: Does the jest documentation address it? (http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/manual-mocks.html) or is it something weird with typescript? It would also be helpful if you had an executable test case showing what you were trying to do and what is actually happening

Comment: the documentation doesn't cover this scenario

Comment: take a look to jest.mock(module,...) --> https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestmockmodulename-factory-options

Comment: @JoséQuintoZamora that works for CommonJS modules

Comment: @kailashyogeshwar did you find an answer for this? i'm kinda stuck on the same... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47376852/jest-manual-mocking-a-package-requiring-new-instance

Comment: @ke3pup yeah i got it working here we need to mock class B here where we are writing the unit test cases so that our class A uses the mocked version of class B

Answer (score 1):

You could use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) to mock `./MyAnotherClass` module and `B` class.

E.g.

`MyClass.ts`:

```js
import { B } from './MyAnotherClass';

export class A {
  f2() {
    const instance = new B();
    instance.someBFunctionFoo('arg');
  }
}
```

`MyAnotherClass.ts`:

```js
export class B {
  someBFunctionFoo(arg) {
    console.log('real someBFunctionFoo implementation');
  }
  someBFunctionBar() {
    console.log('real someBFunctionBar implementation');
  }
}
```

`MyClass.test.ts`:

```js
import { A } from './MyClass';
import { B } from './MyAnotherClass';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';

jest.mock('./MyAnotherClass', () => {
  const mBInstance = { someBFunctionFoo: jest.fn() };
  const mB = jest.fn(() => mBInstance);
  return { B: mB };
});

describe('47093028', () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should pass', () => {
    const a = new A();
    const b = new B();
    mocked(b).someBFunctionFoo.mockImplementationOnce(() => console.log('mock someBFunctionFoo implementation'));
    a.f2();
    expect(b.someBFunctionFoo).toBeCalledWith('arg');
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/47093028/MyClass.test.ts (10.577s)
  47093028
    ✓ should pass (20ms)

  console.log src/stackoverflow/47093028/MyClass.test.ts:18
    mock someBFunctionFoo implementation

------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File        |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files   |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 MyClass.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.96s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/47093028

Comment: This is brilliant!