# Jest manual mocking a package requiring new instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm trying to use `Jest` manual mock to mock the behaviour of a package `X` used 
in a project.

The usage of package `X` within the the actual application code is like so:

```
// Real.js

import X from '../lib/X.js';


export default class App  {

  ...

  execute() {
    const x = new X(); // creating a new instance of X
    x.doSomething();   // calling someThing() of X
  }

  ...

}
```

my **Jest manual mock** to mimic the behaviour of `X` looks like:

```
global.__test__X = () => ({
  doSomething: jest.fn(async () => console.log('mocked async do something')),
  id: (Math.random() * 1000) % 10,
});

module.exports = global.__test__X;
```

In my test i'm trying to see how many times X was called and with what parameters
using the blow code:

```
jest.mock('../X');
import Real from '../Real';
const X = require('../X');

describe('Testing...', async () => {
  it('DoSomething should print mocked console statement', async () => {
    Real.execute(); // this would internally call X.doSomething()
    const x = new X();
    console.log(x.doSomething.mock.calls); // gives []

  });
});
```

Using above, I'm trying to check how many times `X` was called but can't figure out what 
i'm doing wrong since `mock.calls` is always `[]`.  Note that the mock is getting
executed as i can see `mocked async do something`.

Comment: All this info and more has now been added to the Jest docs in a new guide, "ES6 Class Mocks". https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks.html

Answer (score 0):

There's a complete explanation for doing this with jest.mock('./SomeClass'); that applies to this question. ["ES6 class, Automatic mock"](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#automatic-mock) .
let's get started.

```
// ./lib/X.js
export default class X {
  constructor () {
    this.id = '1234567890';
  }

  doSomething = () => {
    return 'Original X';
  }
}
```

Note, the above code has never been called during the test.

This is the resource we want to test, what I mean is, in this class create objects by the class or module that is mocked. We want to make a fake version instead of the original.

```
// Real.js
import X from './lib/X.js';

export default class App  {
  constructor() {
    this.x = new X(); // creating a new instance of X
  }

  execute = () => {
    this.x.doSomething(); // calling someThing() of X
  }
}
```

Accepts a function that should be used as the implementation of the mock. So what we will do is using manual mocks ( __ mocks __ folder) to mock ES6 classes.

```
// ./__mocks__/lib/X.js
module.exports = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    doSomething: jest.fn(() => 'Mocking Original X'),
    id: (Math.random() * 1000) % 10
  }
});
```

When we `import './lib/X.js'` on our test file, Now, in order to test this method without actually hitting the library (and thus creating slow and fragile tests), we immediately use the  mock the `'./lib/X.js'` module.

```
// Real.test.js
import X from './lib/X.js';
import Real from './Real';

jest.mock('./lib/X.js'); // // X module is now a mock constructor

describe('Testing', async () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // Clear all instances and calls to constructor and all methods:
    X.mockClear();
  });


  it('DoSomething should print mocked correct statement', async () => {
    // Ensure our mockClear() is clearing out previous calls to the constructor
    expect(X).not.toHaveBeenCalled(); 

    const real = new Real();
    expect(X).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // Constructor has been called X.js

    real.execute();

    // mock.instances is available with automatic mocks:
    const mockXInstance = X.mock.instances[0];
    const mockDoSomething = mockXInstance.doSomething;
    expect(mockDoSomething).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mockDoSomething.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual('Mocking Original X');
  });
});
```

maybe this is not enough to answer, at least this explains how mock works in similar cases